# embedding open type font

Tags: css, fonts

Why I cannot embed a font ?

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <link href='img/fav.png' rel='icon'>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

<body>
<div id="logo01">Some Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: harrington-normal;
    src: url("harrington-normal.otf") format("opentype");
}
#logo01{
    font-family:harrington-normal;
    font-size:5.9rem;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

`#logo01` is not in harrington font !

`index.php`, `index.css` and `harrington-normal.otf` are all inside the root folder.
I'm using Chrome.

Console says: `GET http://localhost/stenaljubavi.net16.net/up/harrington-normal.otf .....index.php:325`

view page source - line 325 is:
`<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to help you here without access to the files but in general OTF just by itself is not the best way to go about web fonts. Read up here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/